# Bootstrap Dropdown - show selected item closest element is not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap dropdown and showing selected item...

It is working great as expected. But I am getting into problem where if I have multiple dropdowns. If I am changing the one item, all dropdowns are changing... though I am using `closest` element from jQuery...

> **[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/w30aL1u5/)**

**jQuery**

```
jQuery('.th-icons-toggle .dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function() {
  var newIcon = jQuery(this).closest('li').find("a").html();
  jQuery('.dropdown_title').html(newIcon);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h4>Select 1</h4>
<ul class="list-inline th-icons-toggle">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="dropdown_title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i></a></li>  
      <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<h4>Select 2</h4>
<ul class="list-inline th-icons-toggle">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="dropdown_title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></i></a></li>  
      <li><a href="javascript:;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></a></li> 
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `jQuery('.dropdown_title').html(newIcon);` this line says change it on all elements with class `dropdown_title` regardless of `closest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery('.th-icons-toggle .dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function() {
  var newIcon = jQuery(this).closest('li').find("a").html();
  jQuery(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown_title').html(newIcon);
});
```

Comment: Hi **@NiZa**... working like a charm... Thanks for the **TIP**.. I have upvoted your answer and will accept as soon as I can... Thanks

Comment: Thx. Guruprasad Rao answer is also not that bad. So you can also do it that way.

Comment: That is Champ's attitude :)

Answer (score 3):

You are targeting `.dropdown_title` element in general and not in **specific**. Below change should do the trick..

```
jQuery('.th-icons-toggle .dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function() {
  var newIcon = jQuery(this).closest('li').find("a").html();
  jQuery(this).closest('.dropdown').find('.dropdown_title').html(newIcon);
       //^^^get the element with this
});
```

Here is the **[`working fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/w30aL1u5/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

In your first line, `this` is already the anchor tag, so theres no need to go to the parent li to then get the anchor tag again. so you can just do `jQuery(this).html();`

Then you can look for the closest parent that also has `.dropdown_title` as a child and look for it, like this `jQuery(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown_title')`

---

Revissed JQuery below: [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/w30aL1u5/12/)

```
jQuery('.th-icons-toggle .dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function() {
  var newIcon = jQuery(this).html();
  console.log(newIcon);
  jQuery(this).parents('.dropdown').find('.dropdown_title').html(newIcon);
});
```